# How to solve connection time out in Apache Tomcat with application hosted in Microsoft Azure Ubuntu 64-bit instance?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, azure

I have deployed an application over Apache Tomcat 8.0.3 which takes some time to respond (say 3-4 minutes). I have set in the *server.xml* the following configuration

```
<Connector port="8084" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="900000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

But still the connection times out after like a minute or so.

P.S. I am using the organizational network, hence there is a proxy, in which probably the time out actually happens (just guessing).

Is there a way of adding some gifs which might act as response from the server and the connection wouldn't timeout? If so, how and where to add?

Comment: Testing it from outside your network will allow you to confirm whether your guess about the proxy is correct

Comment: well, I would defnitely check that. In the meantime is there any other way to handle that, say with a "busy" gif circle which just keeps on turning.